# I want to pull Row Heading along witht the Top 3 values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Example:

```
Players AtBats  BattingAvg

Dave    20  0.563

Frank   19  0.385

Alex    22  0.500

Chris   19  0.526

Paolo   15  0.571
```

I want to pull the top 3 batting averages along with the batters name.

Comment: Ok, so what's your question to us?  What have you tried already?  Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. You can start a Query from an existing Excel Table. You can sort the data by any column and then Filter to keep the Top 3 rows:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/filter-a-table-HA103993866.aspx

You can output the result of the Query to an Excel Table.